# Compare two CSV files and show only the difference

Tags: perl, shell

I have two [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files:

#### File1.csv

```
Time, Object_Name, Carrier_Name, Frequency, Longname

2013-08-05 00:00, Alpha, Aircel, 917.86, Aircel_Bhopal

2013-08-05 00:00, Alpha, Aircel, 915.13, Aircel_Indore
```

#### File2.csv

```
Time, Object_Name, Carrier_Name, Frequency, Longname

2013-08-05 00:00, Alpha, Aircel, 917.86, Aircel_Bhopal

2013-08-05 00:00, Alpha, Aircel, 815.13, Aircel_Indore
```

These are sample input files in actual so many headers and values will be there, so I can not make them hard coded.

In my expected output I want to keep the first two columns and the last column as it is as there won't be any change in the same and then the comparison should happen for the rest of the columns and values.

Expected output:

```
Time, Object_Name, Frequency, Longname

2013-08-05 00:00, 815.13, Aircel_Indore
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried the `diff` utility in Linux?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some details. Are there always the same number of rows in both files? Can the order of the rows change (and do you care if it does)? Do the fixed columns (first, second, last) or some subset of them act as a column identifier? And most importantly, what should the code output if you have one row that has changes in one column and another row that has changes in another column? Should it output both columns of both rows, or should the unchanged values be left empty? And if the latter, how to distinguish that from a value actually becoming empty?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the links below, there are some examples scripts:

http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/647889-compare-two-csv-files-using-perl
[Perl: Compare Two CSV Files and Print out differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218686/perl-compare-two-csv-files-and-print-out-differences)
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=705049

Comment: I have tried all these options however not fulfilling my requirement.. :(

Comment: I am not familar with Perl, so I cann't give you an accurate example code. But maybe you can use the script from the first link, first answer and instead of pushing the entire row a - parse the line and push the relevent feilds only. There are many examples how to parse a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), here a solution using [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
 #!/bin/bash

 awk -v FS="," '

 function filter_columns()
 {
     return sprintf("%s, %s, %s, %s", $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF);
 }

 NF !=0 && NR == FNR {
    if (NR == 1) {
            print filter_columns();
    } else {
            memory[line++] = filter_columns();
    }
 } NF != 0 && NR != FNR {
    if (FNR == 1) {
            line = 0;
    } else {
            new_line = filter_columns();
            if (new_line != memory[line++]) {
                    print new_line;
            }
    }
 }' File1.csv File2.csv
```

This outputs:

```
Time,  Object_Name,  Frequany, Longname
2013-08-05 00:00,  Alpha,  815.13,  Aircel_Indore
```

Here the explanation:

```
#!/bin/bash

# FS = "," makes awk split each line in fields using
# the comma as separator
awk -v FS="," '

# this function selects the columns you want. NF is the
# the number of field. Therefore $NF is the content of
# the last column and $(NF-1) of the but last.
function filter_columns()
{
     return sprintf("%s, %s, %s, %s", $1, $2, $(NF-1), $NF);
}

# This block processes just the first file, this is the aim
# of the condition NR == FNR. The condition NF != 0 skips the
# empty lines you have in your file. The block prints the header
# and then save all the other lines in the array memory.
NF !=0 && NR == FNR {
    if (NR == 1) {
            print filter_columns();
    } else {
            memory[line++] = filter_columns();
    }
}
# This block processes just the second file (NR != FNR).
# Since the header has been already printed, it skips the first
# line of the second file (FNR == 1). The block compares each line
# against that one saved in the array memory (the corresponding
# line in the first file). The block prints just the lines
# that do not match.
NF != 0 && NR != FNR {
    if (FNR == 1) {
            line = 0;
    } else {
            new_line = filter_columns();
            if (new_line != memory[line++]) {
                    print new_line;
            }
    }
}' File1.csv File2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering @IlmariKaronen's questions would clarify the problem much better, but meanwhile I made some assumptions and took a crack at the problem - mainly because I needed an excuse to learn a bit of Text::CSV.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Array::Compare;
use feature 'say';

open my $in_file, '<', 'infile.csv';
open my $exp_file, '<', 'expectedfile.csv';

open my $out_diff_file, '>', 'differences.csv';

my $text_csv = Text::CSV->new({ allow_whitespace => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

my $line = readline($in_file);
my $exp_line = readline($exp_file);
die 'Different column headers' unless $line eq $exp_line;
$text_csv->parse($line);
my @headers = $text_csv->fields();

my %all_differing_indices;

#array-of-array containings lists of "expected" rows for differing lines
# only columns that differ from the input have values, others are empty
my @all_differing_rows; 

my $array_comparer = Array::Compare->new(DefFull => 1);
while (defined($line = readline($in_file))) {
    $exp_line = readline($exp_file);
    if ($line ne $exp_line) {
        $text_csv->parse($line);
        my @in_fields = $text_csv->fields();
        $text_csv->parse($exp_line);
        my @exp_fields = $text_csv->fields();

        my @differing_indices = $array_comparer->compare([@in_fields], [@exp_fields]);
        @all_differing_indices{@differing_indices} = (1) x scalar(@differing_indices);
        my @output_row = ('') x scalar(@exp_fields);
        @output_row[0, 1, @differing_indices, $#exp_fields] = @exp_fields[0, 1, @differing_indices, $#exp_fields];
        $all_differing_rows[$#all_differing_rows + 1] = [@output_row];
    }
}

my @columns_needed = (0, 1, keys(%all_differing_indices), $#headers);

$text_csv->combine(@headers[@columns_needed]);
say $out_diff_file $text_csv->string();
for my $row_aref (@all_differing_rows) {
    $text_csv->combine(@{$row_aref}[@columns_needed]);   
    say $out_diff_file $text_csv->string();
}
```

It works for the File1 and File2 given in the question and produces the Expected output (except that the Object_Name 'Alpha' is present in the data line - I'm assuming that's a typo in the question).

```
Time,Object_Name,Frequany,Longname
"2013-08-05 00:00",Alpha,815.13,Aircel_Indore
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script for it with very powerful linux tools. [Link here...](http://damian1baran.blogspot.sk/2014/01/linux-unix-compare-two-csv-files.html)

Linux / Unix - Compare Two CSV Files 
This project is about comparison of two csv files.

Let's assume that csvFile1.csv has XX columns and csvFile2.csv has YY columns.

Script I've wrote should compare one (key) column form csvFile1.csv with another (key) column from csvFile2.csv. Each variable from csvFile1.csv (row from key column) will be compared to each variable from csvFile2.csv.

If csvFile1.csv has 1,500 rows and csvFile2.csv has 15,000 total number of combinations (comparisons) will be 22,500,000. So this is very helpful way how to create Availability Report script which for example could compare internal product database with external (supplier's) product database.

Packages used:
csvcut (cut columns)
csvdiff (compare two csv files)
ssconvert (convert xlsx to csv)
iconv
curlftpfs
zip
unzip
ntpd
proFTPD

More you can find on my official blog (+example script): 
http://damian1baran.blogspot.sk/2014/01/linux-unix-compare-two-csv-files.html