# Perl: Compare Two CSV Files and Print out matches (modifying this code)

Tags: perl, csv

I am very new at perl and had discovered the solution at:
[Perl: Compare Two CSV Files and Print out differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218686/perl-compare-two-csv-files-and-print-out-differences)

I have gone through dozens of other solutions and this comes closest, except that instead of finding the differences between 2 CSV files, I want to find where the second CSV file matches the first one in column and row. How could I modify the following script to find the matches in column/row instead of the differences. I am hoping to dissect this code and learn arrays from there, but wanted to find out the solution to this application. Much thanks.

```
use strict;
my @arr1;
my @arr2;
my $a;

open(FIL,"a.txt") or die("$!");
while (<FIL>)
    {chomp; $a=$_; $a =~ s/[\t;, ]*//g; push @arr1, $a if ($a ne  '');};
close(FIL);

open(FIL,"b.txt") or die("$!");
while (<FIL>)
    {chomp; $a=$_; $a =~ s/[\t;, ]*//g; push @arr2, $a if ($a ne  '');};
close(FIL);

my %arr1hash;
my %arr2hash;
my @diffarr;
foreach(@arr1) {$arr1hash{$_} = 1; }
foreach(@arr2) {$arr2hash{$_} = 1; }

foreach $a(@arr1)
{
    if (not defined($arr2hash{$a})) 
     {
        push @diffarr, $a;
     }
}

foreach $a(@arr2)
{
   if (not defined($arr1hash{$a})) 
   { 
       push @diffarr, $a;
   }
}

print "Diff:\n";
foreach $a(@diffarr)
{
    print "$a\n";
}
# You can print to a file instead, by: print FIL "$a\n";
```

ok, I realize that this was more what I was looking for:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    FILE_1  => "file1.txt",
    FILE_2  => "file2.txt",
};

#
# Load Hash #1 with value from File #1
#
my %hash1;
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash1{$value} = 1;
}
close $file1_fh;

#
# Load Hash #2 with value from File #2
#
my %hash2;
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash2{$value} = 1;
}
close $file2_fh;
```

Now I want to search file2's hash to check if there are ANY matches from file1's hash. That is where I am stuck

With new code suggestion, code now looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    FILE_1  => "masterlist.csv",
    FILE_2  => "pastebin.csv",
};

#
# Load Hash #1 with value from File #1
#
my %hash1;
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash1{$value} = 1;
}
close $file1_fh;

    my %hash2;
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    if ( $hash1{$value} ) { 
       print "Match found $value\n";
       $hash2{$value}++;
    }
}
close $file2_fh;

print "Matches found:\n";
foreach my $key ( keys %hash2 ) {
    print "$key found $hash2{$key} times\n";
}
```

I updated one part with split() and it seems to work, but have to test more to confirm if it fits the solution I'm looking for or I have more work to do one it

```
#
# Load Hash #1 with value from File #1
#
my %hash1;  
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;    
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) { 
chomp $value;
$hash1{$value} = ( %hash1, (split(/,/, $_))[1,2] );
}
close $file1_fh;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'matches'? Do you mean independent-but-identical lines in two different files? Do you mean line by line comparison of  both, and 'matching' if and only if that particular line contains the same in both files?
I'm not sure I'd call the code you posted a good starting point - it may well work, but suffers from the usual perl problem of being a bit inscrutable.

Comment: I wanted to match, for example, a single value in one column and row in the first CSV to a value in any column and row in the second CSV. I had found other solutions that match entire lines, but I wanted to just match a single cell. The first CSV will be small and the second CSV would be larger.

Comment: What you need to accomplish this is a hash. Read your CSV file, store the fields you want to find in a hash. Then traverse the other CSV file and print lines that match the hash entries.

Comment: I have updated the issue with more pertinent code

Answer (score 1):

So, with your code there - you've read in 'file1' to a hash.

Why not instead of reading file 2 into a hash, do instead:

```
my %hash2;
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    if ( $hash1{$value} ) { 
       print "Match found $value\n";
       $hash2{$value}++;
    }
}
close $file2_fh;

print "Matches found:\n";
foreach my $key ( keys %hash2 ) {
    print "$key found $hash2{$key} times\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems a lot better, but I receive: ./printmatches.pl
syntax error at ./printmatches.pl line 27, near "if $hash1"
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at ./printmatches.pl line 28.
Global symbol "%hash2" requires explicit package name at ./printmatches.pl line 29.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at ./printmatches.pl line 29.
syntax error at ./printmatches.pl line 31, near "}"
Global symbol "%hash2" requires explicit package name at ./printmatches.pl line 35.
Global symbol "%hash2" requires explicit package name at ./printmatches.pl line 36.

Comment: 27 being: if $hash1{$value} {

Comment: Code snippet edited. Need to declare `%hash2` (and put brackets in the 'if').

Comment: Great! Thanks! it seems to match lines. I wonder how I can get it to match cells or if I can do that in this way. If I have a 2-columned CSV as file one and a 3-columned CSV as file two or a 1-column csv as file one and a 2-columned csv as file 2, it will tell me there was no match. Also, if I switch the columns in file 1 (given both csv's are 2-columned), but not file 2, it will tell me that there is no match.

Comment: The quick and easy way: use `split()`. This isn't 100% reliable though, as CSV does allow you to embed delimiters in fields within quotes. If you're sure that doesn't happen in your data, the `split` will do the trick.

Comment: I will try to use that split(). would this take place at the hash? Do you know how I would integrate split() into this if I knew that the first csv had 2 columns labeled column1;column2 and the second csv had 4 columns labeled column1;columnB;column3;ColumnD ?

Comment: `my ( $col1, $col2, $col3, $col4 ) = split ( ",", $value );`. Then insert whichever column you want to compare into a hash.

Comment: really hate to bug you. last question. Promise :) what would the code look like with that addition: 
my ( $col1, $col2, $col3, $col4 ) = split ( ",", $value );

Answer (score 0):

I think this code identifies every place that a data field in  file A matches a data field in file B (at least it does on my limited test data):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr1;
my @arr2;

# a.txt -> @arr1

my $file_a_name = "poster_a.txt";
open(FIL,$file_a_name) or die("$!");
my $a_line_counter = 0;
while (my $a_line = <FIL>)
{
    $a_line_counter = $a_line_counter + 1;
    chomp($a_line); 
    my @fields = (split /,/,$a_line);
    my $num_fields = scalar(@fields);
    s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @fields;
    push @arr1, \@fields if ( $num_fields ne 0);
};;

close(FIL);
my $file_b_name = "poster_b.txt";
open(FIL,$file_b_name) or die("$!");

while (my $b_line = <FIL>)
{
    chomp($b_line); 
    my @fields = (split /,/,$b_line);    
    my $num_fields = scalar(@fields);
    s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @fields;
    push @arr2, \@fields if ( $num_fields ne 0) 
};
close(FIL);

# b.txt -> @arr2

#print "\n",@arr2, "\n";


my @match_array;
my $file_a_line_ctr = 1;
foreach my $file_a_line_fields (@arr1) 
{
    my $file_a_column_ctr = 1;
    foreach my $file_a_line_field (@{$file_a_line_fields})
    {
        my $file_b_line_ctr = 1;
        foreach my $file_b_line_fields(@arr2)
        {
            my $file_b_column_ctr = 1;
            foreach my $file_b_field (@{$file_b_line_fields})
            {
                if ( $file_b_field eq $file_a_line_field ) 
                {
                    my $match_info = 
                      "$file_a_name line $file_a_line_ctr column $file_a_column_ctr"  .
                      "  (${file_a_line_field}) matches: "  .
                      "$file_b_name line $file_b_line_ctr column $file_b_column_ctr ";
                    push(@match_array, $match_info);
                    print "$match_info \n";
                }
                $file_b_column_ctr = $file_b_column_ctr + 1;
            }
            $file_b_line_ctr = $file_b_line_ctr + 1;               
        }
        $file_a_column_ctr = $file_a_column_ctr + 1;
    }
    $file_a_line_ctr = $file_a_line_ctr + 1;
}
print "there were ", scalar(@match_array)," matches\n";
```

Comment: cool! This works too, but it only seems to match complete lines. If there are identical columns in the same order, it matches. Add an extra column to the second file, and nothing. this is also csv, I'm not sure if it was tested with a text file

Comment: @perlstudent It doesn't have to match a whole line in my test data. If I have one line 1,2,3,4,5 in the first file, and 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the second, I get 5 matches. Same if I have a,b,c,d,e,f in the first and a,b,c,d,e in the second. Can you provide your test data?

Comment: sure my first file is: uname;e-mail
john;john@company.com
jane;jane@company.com

Comment: second file is: uname;e-mail;column3
john;john@company.com;column3
jo;jo@company.com;column3
bo;bo@company.com;column3

Comment: You are using **semi-colons** as the delimiter instead of a **comma**. So the split statement needs to be modified to use a semi-colon. Once that is done it matches the John fields and the john@company.com fields and also the header fields uname and email. The header fields can be removed by not pushing the line 1 data of each file in the initial read loops. That also would require the final loop line_ctr's to start at 2 to give accurate information.

Comment: ahhhh I see, let me try quick

Comment: swapped , for ; and now I get: file a line 1 column 1 matches: file b line 1 column 1 
file a line 1 column 2 matches: file b line 1 column 2 
file a line 2 column 1 matches: file b line 2 column 1 
file a line 2 column 2 matches: file b line 2 column 2

Comment: You should add (${file_a_line_field}) before the "matches" to see what the field values are. But that is correct - "uname" matches, "email" matches, "john" matches and "john@company.com" matches. 4 total matches. It is correct output. If you don't like the format, you can change that.